# SQL Server : trigger on Bulk Update

Tags: sql, t-sql

How do I change the trigger below to work on bulk updates? In the trigger, I get the incoming `ActivityTypeID`. If the value is '32E490BB-DA7E-E811-80D9-00155D012204', then I make sure my `IsBillable` column is set to 0, otherwise I set the column to 1.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_WorklogInsert1]
ON  [dbo].[WorkLog]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ActivityTypeID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

    SET @ActivityTypeID = (SELECT [ActivityType_Id] FROM inserted);

    IF @ActivityTypeID = '32E490BB-DA7E-E811-80D9-00155D012204'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE w
        SET w.IsBillable = 0
        FROM [dbo].[WorkLog] AS w
        INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON w.Id = i.Id
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE w
        SET w.IsBillable = 1
        FROM [dbo].[WorkLog] AS w
        INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON w.Id = i.Id
    END
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good day,

Please check if bellow trigger solve your needs:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_WorklogInsert1] ON  [dbo].[WorkLog] AFTER INSERT,UPDATE AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE w
        set w.IsBillable = 
        CASE 
            WHEN i.ActivityType_Id = '32E490BB-DA7E-E811-80D9-00155D012204'
                THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END
    FROM [dbo].[WorkLog] as w
    INNER JOIN inserted as i on w.Id = i.Id
END
GO
```

**Note!** As much as I understand your question it is not related to bulk insert but to multiple rows that are inserted together (your version of the trigger cover only a case that you insert/update single row). If this is not the case, then please elaborate.

Comment: By the way, if you do want to use BULK INSERT then you should use the parameter FIRE_TRIGGERS. If FIRE_TRIGGERS is not specified, no insert triggers execute.

Comment: Is it that a Case statement works on multiple rows whereas an IF statement does not?  Does the use of my variable in the original trigger have an impact as well?  I'll research multiple row insert.  If there is another term you think I should read up on, please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: @marc_s I would appreciate it if you will not mess up my answers! This is not a Wiki shared article or a hsared answer, but my personal answer under my name. and I really don't like the way you take the credit by changing nothing, or format the code in a way I think it is not recommended and less readable.

Comment: Just trying to make things a bit **consistent** (e.g. the capitalization of keywords) and clean up the SQL code to make it more readable. And **YES**- this ***IS*** a shared editing environment - if you don't llike it - don't post here

Comment: You are wrong  marc_s! If I wanted to make it a shared answer I should have mark the "community wiki" which I did not! This is personal answer in my personal approach. There is a built-in option in the interface for shared answer by marking the check box "community wiki" ;-)

Comment: By the way, (1) thanks for the willing to approve but comments could do the same work and better way. By telling people what they should do differently orr change according to your opinion, they can learn (assuming they agree). (2) I agree with the UPPER CASE approach and I kept it, but not with the breaking of lines.

Comment: Hi guys.  I generated the syntax from SQL scripting so I assumed the formatting was acceptable.  Thanks for the feedback and answers.

Comment: You are most welcome @BillGreer . I glad I could help a bit ;-)